# Burndown analysis in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to prepare my data to create a burndown visual. As you can see the `Rate` column isn't simply A - B, as it carries forward the previous value if B is null.

I've tried some case statements using lag and sums but no avail.

Some direction on the case statement or an optimal solution would be ideal.

For example, this is how my data looks:

| ID | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | NULL |
| 2 | 20 | 3 |
| 3 | 20 | NULL |
| 4 | 20 | 7 |
| 5 | 20 | NULL |
| 6 | 20 | NULL |
| 7 | 20 | NULL |
| 8 | 20 | 5 |
| 9 | 20 | 7 |

And I want a rate column that looks like this.

| ID | A | B | Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | NULL | 20 |
| 2 | 20 | 3 | 17 |
| 3 | 20 | NULL | 17 |
| 4 | 20 | 7 | 10 |
| 5 | 20 | NULL | 10 |
| 6 | 20 | NULL | 10 |
| 7 | 20 | NULL | 10 |
| 8 | 20 | 5 | 5 |
| 9 | 20 | 7 | -2 |

Comment: Does your table also have an id/sequence/timestamp column?

Comment: To expand on jarh's comment, you need some way how you sort the data / table, how do define the order of rows? This is needed for your design to work.

Comment: Without some kind of column to denote the order of your data, what you are after simply isn't posible. If you do, this is, effectively, just `A - <Cumulative SUM of B>`; there are plenty of examples of how to achieve a cumulative `SUM` in SQL Server.

Comment: @jarlh yes the table has an ascending date/id column, which can be used for an order by

Comment: @Peter206 I've added the ID column now to the post, I'll try a cumulative sum

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Larnu for the guidance.

Here is the solution when you have your data partitioned by some group ID and ordered by some data or row ID.

```
SELECT
GROUP_ID,
ROW_ID,
COL_A,
COL_B,
COL_A - (SUM(ISNULL(COL_B,0)) OVER (PARTITION BY GROUP_ID ORDER BY ROW_ID ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW))
FROM table
```